# Sql query fails to execute when returning to base method afer having been directed to a separate method

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I have some code which resembles the following in C#:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    try
    {
        Apple();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Some error message ...");
    }            
}

public void Apple()
{   
    while (counta == 1)
    {           
        SQLDataReader myReader = null;
        //SQL query & connection code goes here ...

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("bbb");
        }
        try
        {
            Pear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        //some other simple code here       
    }
}

public void Pear()
{   
    //Do something here
    MessageBox.Show("ccc");
}
```

When I attempt to run this code, the connection to the database and the execution of the `SQL` query works fine for the first time [the MessageBox (with **bbb** as its message) pops up], but after running the `Pear()` method, the `SQL` query in `Apple()` *fails* to run during the next iteration of the while loop (even though counta = 1) [the MessageBox (with **bbb** as its message) does ***not*** pop up]. Inserting a break-point at different locations in the code [both before and after the call to `Pear()`] and debugging with these break-points seem to indicate that `VS2017` is able to follow the sequence accurately (from `Apple()` to `Pear()` & back to `Apple()` ...), but one would expect the `MessageBox` (with **bbb** as its message) to show up for *each* iteration of the while loop (so long as counta = 1), although this strangely does not happen (this `MessageBox` only shows up when `Apple()` is run for the first time). However, the `MessageBox` (with **ccc** as its message) shows up for each iteration of the while loop.

Please advise on what could be causing the `SQL` query to be 'skipped' in this instance, and how this may be resolved.

Thanks.

Comment: You say the sql query is running fine but i don't see code that is calling any database. Please be more specific or post more code

Comment: The SQL Query is found within the line given in this example as the commented section //SQL query & connection code goes here. I am actually more interested to know why the MessageBox (with "bbb" as its message) is able to pop-up for the first time this code is run (indicating that the SQL query was successfully executed), but subsequently, this MessageBox failed to pop-up. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any exceptions? you are hiding all the code, with this few information how can we guess what is going on?

Comment: @Nerevar: No, there were no exceptions.

Comment: From what I observed, C# seems to be skipping the execution of the SQL DataReader after the first iteration of the while loop in Apple(), which is why I decided to pose this question on SO to see if anyone else has faced a similar problem & knows how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found the reason - evidently if the SQL query (when executed) does not return any records, C# merely skips executing the SQLDataReader entirely, rather than throw an exception, which was what I was expecting.